# Excel Macro (VBA) that checks cell values against a list in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks, one that is data (We'll call WB 1) that needs the values in column k checked against values on another workbook (We'll call WB 2) that contains the true values for the entries. Each entry has a quantity attached to it so the price varies dependent on that. WB 1 is in a list with entries on each row and WB 2 has an item on each row and each column is the price for that quantity. I need a macro that will check these values against each other and replace any values on WB 1 with the correct value from WB 2.

Example Data:

```
WB 1
    | Column A  | Column C | Column K |
     ---------------------------------
    | Item Name |    30    |  $5.42   |

WB 2
    | Column A  | Column F | Column G | Column H | ... |
                     15         30         45
     --------------------------------------------------
    | Item Name |  $2.86   |   $4.53  |  $6.00   | ... |
```

Comment: What's preventing you from acheiving this?  Questions which are just a description of your requirements typically get closed here.

Comment: Oh sorry! Completely forgot to post why. I have been unable to load the reference file using vba. Also I have been having trouble getting it to line by line search and replace based off of the two data points used to define which cell is correct for that specific cells value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code snippet

*points to remember

Phase 1: Loading the workbook

1. You would need to first refer the source workbook by path or call it as loading the workbook.
2. Then assign the source workbook say(set sourceworkbook = "workbook derived from the path and assigned to a variable"
3. Many code is available in stackoverflow to achieve the same.

Phase 2: Calculation/Manipulation/Logic

```
lastRow = SourceData.Rows.Count

For rowIndex= 2 to lastRow
  lTemp = sourceWorksheet.Cells(rowIndex, "Q").Value
  lDigit = VLOOKUP( value, table, index_number, [not_exact_match] )  'not_exact_match is usually false
  DestinationWorksheet.Cells(rowIndex, "AM").Value = lDigit
next rowIndex
```

[Remember to declare the variables with appropriate datatypes matching your requirement]/

Regards,
Mani

Answer (score 0):

you can use vlookup to perform a search and follow the instruction below for better performance.

1. set the WB1 as source and WB2 as destination work.
2. select the item in WB1 with a "For loop". Make sure you select the appropriate column and its tuple

   For rowIndex = 2 To lastRow

(Alternatively use a range)

3. Perform a vlookup between the search.
4. paste/display the output in required column
5. Increment the loop (Next Row index).

(let me know if you need exact code snippets)

Regards,
Mani

Comment: Code snippets would be appreciated as I'm not too familiar with doing things in Excel in regards to referencing. Thanks for the quick reply